# Sort a dictionary

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, dictionary

```
sorted_event_types={}
        for key,value in sorted(event_types.items()):
            sorted_event_types[key]=value


(Pdb) print sorted_event_types
{'ch': 1, 'eh': 2, 'oh': 3, 'ah': 0, 'as': 1, 'cs': 0, 'os': 5, 'es': 9}
(Pdb) event_types
{'as': 1, 'ch': 1, 'eh': 2, 'oh': 3, 'cs': 0, 'ah': 0, 'os': 5, 'es': 9}
```

I want to sort a dictionary and keep it that way.

The output should be `{'ah': 1, 'as': 1, 'ch': 2, 'cs': 3, 'eh': 0, ...}`

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: See [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) (although I would probably turn it into a list instead, as I like the separation)

Comment: Sadly the duplicate question has OrderedDict (whether or not it is appropriate) answers rather buried..

Comment: IMHO the duplicate question is not related with what OP is asking. I think [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/python-dictionary-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared) is more relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionaries are unordered collections. You can create [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) with your sorted data to keep the order:

```
>>> import collections
>>> sorted_event_types = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(event_types.items()))
>>> print sorted_event_types
OrderedDict([('ah', 0), ('as', 1), ('ch', 1), ('cs', 0), ('eh', 2), ('es', 9), ('oh', 3), ('os', 5)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries do not have any sense of order, they are unordered collections of key:value pairs.

If you want to maintain the order, you should use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) . Example -

```
import collections
sorted_event_types = collections.OrderedDict()
for key,value in sorted(event_types.items()):
    sorted_event_types[key]=value
```